# Comparing features in GIS interface with Google Maps/Bing Basemaps - Which Co-ordinate system to use?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-maps, coordinate-system, editing

I want to compare some Geographic features in my data with Google maps in ArcGIS platform using a third party application.

But I prefer the output to be in Local UTM cordinates.

What is the best practice?

(a) Use the WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere ( WKID: 3857) for my data; or

(b) Use local UTM cordinate system for editing, and do a transformation, in case editing throws errors?

Comment: Just a heads up you shouldn't really be using Google maps to digitise anything: "You may not use Google Maps or Google Earth as the basis for tracing your own maps or other geographic content." http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

Comment: That was very important information.I would change the Question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You should never do any serious GIS work in EPSG:3857 as that projection is (or should be, at least) for visualization only. I would convert the data to a local CRS or UTM zone to do any sort of analysis.